# Count all the nested relationship records using Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, query-builder

Currently, I am building comments for a post whose model looks this:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'post_id', 'parent_comment_id', 'text', 'is_approved', 'upvotes', 'downvotes'];

    protected $with = ['post'];

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'post_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_comment_id');
    }
}
```

And, shortly the database is:

| id | parent_comment_id | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | Text 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Text 2 |
| 3 | 2 | Text 3 |
| 4 | 3 | Text 4 |
| 5 | 4 | Text 5 |

For example: if Comment ID (1) is selected then, the total replies should be 4 but not 1. Because all the records are a child of Comment ID (1). Likewise, if Comment ID (2) is selected, then count is 3.

Here is my query which I have done:

```
Comment::query()
    ->without('post')
    ->with('user:id,name,email,role,picture')
    ->withCount('replies')
    ->where('parent_comment_id', request()->input('comment_id', null))
    ->where('post_id', $id)
    ->orderByDesc('replies_count')
    ->paginate(2)
    ->withQueryString()
    ->fragment('post-comments');
```

**Now, how can I show the total replies to the comment?**

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a package like [staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list](https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list) that allows you to define recursive relationships.

```php
class Comment extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\LaravelAdjacencyList\Eloquent\HasRecursiveRelationships;

    public function getParentKeyName()
    {
        return 'parent_comment_id';
    }

    public function recursiveReplies()
    {
        return $this->hasManyOfDescendants(Comment::class);
    }
}

Comment::withCount('recursiveReplies')->get();
```

Comment: I am just looking for a solution that recursive the query on the SQL SERVER, not the backend PHP SERVER.

Comment: @JSTECH Yeah, that's exactly what it does. It uses query expressions to achieve this. So it doesn't introduce a n + 1 problem :)

Comment: Sorry, the query might be a little complex and not something I could write off the top of my head. You can always look into the source code and find out for yourself. Here is a good starting point: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list/blob/b3047c414cbf54ce49b7b5072552627387f80eb3/src/Eloquent/Traits/HasOfDescendantsRelationships.php#L22

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example code for counting nested relationship records in Laravel Eloquent.

If you have a Comment model and you want to count the records where the **parent_comment_id**
is greater than or equal to a specific value (provided as **comment_id** in the request),
you can use the following code:

```
$parent_comment_id = request()->input('comment_id', null);
$getComments = Comment::when($parent_comment_id !== null, function ($query) use ($parent_comment_id) {
    return $query->where('parent_comment_id', '>=', $parent_comment_id);
})->count();
```

This code checks if the **comment_id** is provided in the request, and if it is,
it counts the comments where **parent_comment_id** is greater than or equal to the specified value.

```
$parent_comment_id = request()->input('comment_id', null);
$comments = Comment::query()
    ->without('post')
    ->with('user:id,name,email,role,picture')
    ->withCount('replies')
    ->when($parent_comment_id !== null, function ($query) use ($parent_comment_id) {
        return $query->where('parent_comment_id', '>=', $parent_comment_id);
    })
    ->where('post_id', $id)
    ->orderByDesc('replies_count')
    ->paginate(2)
    ->withQueryString()
    ->fragment('post-comments');
```

This code not only fetches comments with related user information and reply counts but also
filters the comments based on the provided **comment_id**. It then paginates the results and prepares the query string for pagination.

This structured format clarifies how to count nested relationship records and how the provided Eloquent query is related to the question.